mismatch between python 3.12 and mysql-connector-python 8.0.15. how can i uninstall connector python 8.0 and install the 8.4 on ubunto
i have ubunto 24.04 lts on my system and python 3.12. i have installed connector/python 8.0.15 and i cant to connect my database.
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='mypass', host='localhost', database='db')

my error is:
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 102, in __init__
     self.connect(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 735, in connect
     self._open_connection()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 250, in _open_connection
     self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 155, in _do_auth
     self._socket.switch_to_ssl(ssl_options.get('ca'),
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 427, in switch_to_ssl
     self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

i have to install connector/python version 8.4 on my ubunto but dont know how to uninstall it and install the new verion

How did you install connector 8.0.15?  Every install thing has an uninstall or upgrade option.

sudo apt-get  install python3-mysql.connector

I suggest you apt remove that and then sudo pip install mysqlx-connector-python.

Do yo found how to solve the issue?
